# How to display Javascript Variable value to HTML Document

Tags: javascript

If I use document.write() it clears the whole html document. So how can I take this javascript variable

`var beforenoonprice = 6.75;`

and have it display to the html document through this div

```
 <div id="beforeNoonCPSlot"></div>
```

Comment: beforeNoonCPSlot.innerHTML=beforenoonprice; is the simplest

Comment: @dandavis: Ugh, automatic globals, blech. ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: smoke em if ya got em! (not much can we do about em anyway)

Comment: @dandavis: But **do** you? What if you've declared a variable with that name? Or any of the *(waves hands)* fifteen other ways the automatic global can be overrridden? :-) There's a *reason* you don't see them relied on in most code...

Comment: if one has unexpected globals floating around thier code, they've got other concerns to address. but you need IDs, and IDs make globals, so these are actually among the only globals you should have; why not use them again?. when i'm using global ID access, i typically use hungarian on the element's id: inpLogin, chkTOS, selDays, etc, so collisions aren't much of a problem. i think it's one of vanilla's most under-rated features, especially on SPAs. i'm glad the capability is there and widely supported.

Answer (score 3):

You use the DOM API:

```
document.getElementById("beforeNoonCPSlot").innerHTML = String(beforenoonprice);
```

[List of DOM API specs](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR).

*(In the above, I've explicitly converted the price to a string, but that's just for emphasis; if I hadn't, there would have been an* implicit *conversion.)*

Note that you have to execute that line of code **after** the element has been created, otherwise we can't find it with `document.getElementById`. Given that you've said that using `document.writeln` cleared the whole document, it sounds like you're running your code at a point where the document as a whole has been rendered, so that should be fine.